# Issue Binding an iOS Swift library

Tags: ios, swift, xamarin, native

I have done everything in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/binding-swift/walkthrough till the step where I need to generate API definition file for the binding. I have used the correct sdk version and my command is "sharpie bind -framework ./Desktop/Keyless/sdk-ios-master/CoreMoboKey.framework -sdk iphoneos14.2". However it still show error like "**function does not return NSString**", "**Could not build module 'Foundation'**"

Comment: if building for x86_64 require ios_simulator=yes option.

Comment: @AdrainZhu-MSFT Hi may I know where this should be configured? I keep getting error like below
" In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:12:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSBundle.h:91:143: error: 
      function does not return NSString"

Comment: In tool sharpie https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/macios/binding/objective-sharpie/tools?context=xamarin/ios